# Returning out of function gives None

Tags: python, function, return, primes

```
def prime_func():
    counter = 0
    composites = [2]
    primes = [3]
    for x in range(4, 50):
        for y in range(2, x):
            a = x/y
            if a - int(a) == 0:
                composites = composites + [x]
            else:
                primes = primes + [x]
                counter = counter + 1
                if counter == args[1]:
                    return counter, composites, primes
                else:
                    pass

prime_func()

counter1, composites1, primes1 = prime_func()

print(counter1)
```

FYI, this is my first official Python script. In case you want context, this will eventually calculate the xth prime number once given an input **(I didn't include this bit,** don't be confused by the `args` part).

When running this code I receive the error message `NoneType object is not iterable`. I looked online and this message is mostly given when the function is not actually returning anything. Can someone help me with the structure so that it works?

Originally `counter`, `composites`, and `primes` were defined outside of the function and given as inputs but I changed this around to see if anything would change.

I'm told that variables such as these (global?) shouldn't be set inside of a function.

Comment: At the bottom of your function you do not return anything.  Thus the None.  You will need to return something, if you don't want `None` returned.

Comment: I was wondering about this... I returned three variables conditionally under the "if" statement. Is that not one way to return values?

Comment: Yes that is, but what about the other exit points of the function?

Comment: What @StephenRauch said.  Put in a "dummy value" return statement at the end of the function with known values.  If THAT'S what's returned, it means your loops are ending without the If-statement ever being true.

Comment: Why are you calling `prime_func()` twice?  The first call appears to be useless, as you aren't saving the results.

Comment: @JohnGordon these are the small things I still need clarification about. I didn't realize that declaring the output of a function also calls it. You're right, it doesn't make a difference, I've removed the first call.

Comment: `else: pass` does nothing. Simply remove this redundant code.

Answer (score 1):

I assumes there are just not enough primes in the given range 0 .. 49, so the break condition `counter == args[1]` never applies and the function returns None.

It is better to pass all important parameters into a function and don't use hard coded constants, this make your functions more flexible.

For a more efficient algorithm look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

```
def is_prime(a):
    for y in range(2, a):
        if a % y == 0:  # the modulo operation finds the remainder after division
            return False
    return True

# pass end condition into function, args[1] is a global variable
def prime_func(max_value, max_prime_count=10): 
    # you don't need a counter len(primes) do the same, also counter should start a 1
    primes = [3]

    for x in range(4, max_value):
        if is_prime(x):
            primes.append(x)
            if len(primes) == max_prime_count:
                break  # max prime count reached

    # calculates composites by set operation
    composites = set(range(2, max_value)) - set(primes)
    # also works if max_prime_count is not reached
    return sorted(composites), primes


composites, primes = prime_func(50, 10)

print(composites)
print(primes)
print(len(primes))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you should try to return the value at every possible exit point in the function. If at all the code arrives at point and there is no return or no further operations, it will be returned as None

as in your code,if the code completes the for loop and it did not go to any of the return statements, it will be returned as None

Comment: Okay thanks, I'm slowly figuring this out. Do you have any idea why the function isn't exiting where I would like? If `args[1]` is less than 50 then it should be reached at some point, right?

Comment: you mentioned args[1]==counter right?, it could be that args[1] never equals to counter or that condition did not become true. or it could be that args[1] and counter have different data types

Answer (score 0):

Missing `break` in a couple spots. Also, this work-in-progress is not a prime number finder at this point, it will simple find even and odd numbers because of how the loops are structured.